# In Spring Boot 2.0 web app how to access Java variable from within static Javascript file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have static Javascript file main.js declaring below variable:

```
var base = '/localhost:8382/myservice'  // for dev
//var base = '/example.com/myservice'  // for prod
```

They have different value depending on spring profile dev or prod. I can define this variable in application.properties for dev and prod profiles. But how I can access this variable from within main.js ?

Currently I have to manually comment out one or the other in main.js depending on profile.

Comment: Which template engine do you use ?

Comment: thyemleaf. One way to do is using inline js in thymeleaf but I want to know if possible in static js file.

Comment: How does this question relates to spring batch? Please use the right tags for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on Thymeleaf2. If you are using 3, you can see [this official doc(Link)](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#template-modes) and [an example(Link)](https://github.com/jmiguelsamper/thymeleaf3-template-modes-example/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/js/common.js)

I'd add a `script` tag in a HTML like this

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var headParam = {
        baseModelValue: /*[[@{${base}}]]*/,
        baseBeanValue: /*[[@{${@customProperties.base}}]]*/
    }
</script>
```

Note that I used `@{...}` because the values are URLs. You don't have to use it if you don't want Thymeleaf to rewrite your URLs. You should not use it if it's not URLs.

You can use it from js files like `headParam.baseModelValue`

- Use like `baseModelValue` if you are passing values using a controller with `Model`.
- Use like `baseBeanValue` if you are using properties files and profiles. `customProperties` is a bean name using `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

An example of `CustomProperties` class:

```
@Repository
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class CustomProperties {
    private String base;

    //Getters & setters
}
```

and a YAML file:

```
---
spring: 
  profiles: dev

foo:
  base: /localhost:8382/myservice
---
spring: 
  profiles: prod

foo:
  base: /example.com/myservice
```